# Why Euler characteristics can be calculated by Poincaré-Hopf Index formula?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

How to convince myself of the following apparently paradoxical statement?

> **Poincaré-Hopf Index formula:** The Euler characteristic is equal to the sum of *winding numbers* of a smooth vector field on the compact, oriented manifold $M$.

On one hand, winding numbers on an $n$-manifold $M$, depend only on the top homology group; i.e. $H_n(M)$. On the other hand 
$$\chi(M)=\sum_i (-1)^i b_i,\qquad b_i=\mathrm{rank}(H_i(M)).$$

In first case, $\chi(M)$ depends only $H_n(M)$ and in second one it depends on all homology groups. What is wrong?

Comment: The Euler characteristic can also be computed as the self-intersection number of the zero section of the tangent bundle of $M$ (which I guess is equivalent to the Index formula). I guess that looking at the details of a proof why these numbers are all the same will give you more insight to answer your question.

Comment: For instance in *Characteristic Classes* by John Milnor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement that the winding number only depends on the top homology group of $M$ is misleading; it depends on the choice of vector field as well. Which vector fields will be available is very much dependent on the topology of $M$ and not just on its top homology group; e.g. there is one with no zeros on a torus but not the sphere.

Comment: You mean the $2$-sphere I guess :-)